# How to know which partition/volume is which EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

On an EC2 instance, I have a few partitions that look like these:

```
/dev/nvme1n1     15G   48M   15G   1% /data/mongo2
/dev/nvme2n1     15G  4.7G   11G  32% /data/docker
/dev/nvme3n1     15G  3.4G   12G  23% /data/mongo
```

And then the corresponding EBS volumes, one of which looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out which mounts map to which EBS volumes. It used to be the case that the "Attachment information" matched or was similar to the device, but it no longer seems to be the case with nve.

Is there any way to match these besides keeping track myself of the mounts? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different methods depending on what OS you're using.

> With Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.01 or later (including Amazon Linux 2), you can run the ebsnvme-id command as follows to map the NVMe device name to a volume ID and device name

```
sudo /sbin/ebsnvme-id /dev/nvme1n1
```

Which will provide output like this:

> Volume ID: vol-01324f611e2463981
>   /dev/sdf

For Linux kernels 4.2 and later you can do the following:

First, install `nvme-cli`.  It is the  NVMe command line package.
Next you can run a command similar to this:

```
sudo nvme id-ctrl -v /dev/nvme1n1
```

> NVME Identify Controller:
>   vid     : 0x1d0f
>   ssvid   : 0x1d0f
>   sn      : vol01234567890abcdef
>   mn      : Amazon Elastic Block Store
>   ...
>   0000: 2f 64 65 76 2f 73 64 6a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 "/dev/sdf..."

The links below provide additional details.

**References**

[NVME EBS Volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html)
[How to Find EBS Volume ID for NVME Volume](https://medium.com/@ripon.banik/how-to-find-ebs-volume-id-for-nvme-volume-1148d7499dc)

Comment: Awesome. I'm running amazon linux and the first command was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for NON-nvme instances? ebsnvme-id is super handy for NVMe instances, but what non-NVMe instances?